ggsurvfit::add_risktable() - show final cumulative incidence
I have a question regarding risk tables for cumulative incidence plots using the ggsurvfit package in R.
Sometimes in my work, the maximum follow-up time is not a nice/round number or it may be different between strata, but I'd still like to be able to show the final cumulative incidence reflecting the total cumulative events. For example, in the figure below, max follow-up time is 4.67 months, but the final cumulative incidence is displayed at 5 months.

I can't figure out how to do this with ggsurvfit.
Is there a way to "force in" the final cumulative incidence at 25 months in the example below?
library(ggsurvfit)
survfit2(Surv(ttdeath, death_cr) ~ trt, tidycmprsk::trial) |> 
  ggcuminc(outcome = "death from cancer") +
  add_risktable(
  risktable_stats =
    c("{n.risk}",
    "{cum.event}",
    "{round((estimate)*100)}%"),
  stats_label = c("At Risk", 
                  "Cumulative Events",
                  "Cumulative Incidence"),
  size = 3) +
  scale_ggsurvfit(x_scales = list(breaks = seq(0, 25, by = 5),
                                  limits = c(-1, 26))) #set limits to avoid text cutoff


Thank you!

I don’t understand the question. If you do not have data out to 5 months or 25 months, then exact what lie do you want the graphics to display?

It might be best to use the max that is at the maximum observed time or less. Like "breaks = seq(0, 24, by = 6)" for the example above to make it look pretty. To force it in assumes the same cumulative incidences of Drug A and B for month 23.9 to be the same as month 25.00 if you look at summary(survfit2(Surv(ttdeath, death_cr) ~ trt, tidycmprsk::trial)). It's NA because the number at risk is 0 at month 25 and dividing by 0 is undefined.

Thanks to those who responded!
I understand that cumulative incidence is technically undefined at time > max (observed time). However, I'd like to still display the final cumulative incidence in situations like my first example above:

max observed time was 4.67 months with many cases after 4 months, so if the risk table only went until 4 months, it wouldn't show the final cumulative incidence at the end of follow-up.

I know the trial dataset is not the best example for this question because max(ttdeath)=24, so I could just use "breaks = seq(0, 24, by = 6)", as one of the responses mentioned. But let's pretend max(ttdeath) was 24.67 and I wanted to display the risk table through time=25.
I was able to come up with a workaround by using conditional logic to replace the missing estimates with max cumulative incidence. It's not the most elegant solution, so other suggestions or improvements to my code are still welcome. Thanks!
# Generate survival/cumulative incidence data
library(ggsurvfit)
cuminc <- survfit2(Surv(ttdeath, death_cr) ~ trt, tidycmprsk::trial) |> 
  ggcuminc(outcome = "death from cancer")

# Pull maximum cumulative incidence
max_cuminc <- cuminc$data|> group_by(strata) |> summarize(max_cuminc=round((max(estimate))*100))
max_cumincA <- max_cuminc |> filter(strata=='Drug A') |> pull(max_cuminc)
max_cumincB <- max_cuminc |> filter(strata=='Drug B') |> pull(max_cuminc)

# Plot
cuminc +
 add_risktable(
  risktable_stats =
    c("{n.risk}",
    "{cum.event}",
    #"{round((estimate)*100)}%"), #NA for last estimate
    "{case_when(!is.na(estimate) ~ round(estimate*100),
                is.na(estimate) & strata=='Drug A' ~ max_cumincA,
                is.na(estimate) & strata=='Drug B' ~ max_cumincB)}%"), #workaround
  stats_label = c("At Risk", 
                  "Cumulative Events",
                  "Cumulative Incidence"),
  size = 3
) +
  scale_ggsurvfit(x_scales = list(breaks = seq(0, 25, by = 5),
                                  limits = c(-1, 26))) #set limits to avoid text cutoff


